# Move blob within Google bucket using Google Cloud Storage library

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage

I have a Spark job in which I want to move a text file within Google Cloud Storage bucket from directory A to directory B using google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions

source file path = "gs://spark-bucket/directoryA/subdirectoryA/textfile.txt"

dest bucket location = "gs://spark-bucket/directoryA/subdirectoryB/"

What should be the sourceBucketName, blobName and destBucketName? Does it have to be the  entire path "gs://spark-bucket/directoryA/subdirectoryA/" or just the bucket name i.e. "spark-bucket" based on the above source file path?

```
val storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder.setProjectId("project-id").build.getService
val blobId = BlobId.of(sourceBucketName, blobName)
val blob = storage.get(blobId)
val copyWriter = blob.copyTo(destBucketName, destBlobName)
blob.delete();
```

Comment: `sourceBucketName = 'spark-bucket'`,  `blobName = 'directoryA/subdirectoryA/textfile.txt'`

Comment: @blackbishop tried this, but the file was not moved. I'm checking the logs in spark history server and I don't see any application logs (println statements). Also I don't see any exceptions or errors, the job completed successfully. I'm new to GCP so not sure why the logs are not shown

Comment: @blackbishop I do see an exception while executing this method.
diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:88)
 at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:88)
 at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:74)
 at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:75)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to move `textfile.txt` from `gs://spark-bucket/directoryA/subdirectoryA/` to `gs://spark-bucket/directoryA/subdirectoryB/`

From your question it is clear that you have one bucket i.e. spark-bucket. So both **sourceBucketName** and **destBucketName** are the same i.e. `spark-bucket`.

Now there are other two parameters i.e. **blobName** and **destBlobName**.

In your case **blobName** should be `directoryA/subdirectoryA/textfile.txt` and **destBlobName** should be `directoryA/subdirectoryB/textfile.txt`.

So in short -

```
sourceBucketName = “spark-bucket”
destBucketName = “spark-bucket”
blobName = “directoryA/subdirectoryA/textfile.txt”
destBlobName = “directoryA/subdirectoryB/textfile.txt”
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I don't see any logs printed from my application in spark history server. I'm submitting job using
spark-submit --class com.main.class --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 2 --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 2 gs://bucket/jarname.jar 10 
Is there any way to see the logs printed from println from the application.

Comment: This is a completely different question from the initial question. So I would suggest you put it as a separate question so that you can get necessary help.